# What does the circleci 'error connecting build-agent container to ephemeral network: "Invalid name or ID supplied:"' mean?

Tags: docker, circleci

I'm attempting to use the circleci cli tool to test my build configurations locally but whatever I do I keep getting the error:

```
$  circleci local execute --job test
Fetching latest build environment...
Docker image digest: sha256:0d6c17bb09da8707eabad913d61a68b28028906d48c176d6bd60ebd36cce222e
====>> Spin up environment
Build-agent version  ()
System information:
 Server Version: 20.10.20
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Kernel Version: 5.15.74-1-lts
 Operating System: Arch Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64

Error:
Unexpected environment preparation error: error connecting build-agent to ephemeral network: error connecting build-agent container to ephemeral network: Error response from daemon: invalid name or ID supplied: ""

Step failed
Task failed
Error: Unhandled prepare executor error: error connecting build-agent to ephemeral network: error connecting build-agent container to ephemeral network: Error response from daemon: invalid name or ID supplied: ""
```

I get this error for any job in any project on my machine indicating that it's something wrong with my system not the project.  I can even run these commands fine on other machines.  It something wrong with this machine but I have no idea what this error means.  "invalid name or ID" to what? What is the thing with name or ID ""?

##### Update

Checking the docker systemctl logs I can see where circleci is getting the error:

```
Oct 27 13:36:46 myhost dockerd[1238]: time="2022-10-27T13:36:46.455536188-05:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/networks/a878ce01450ef752f4610bca358d4bf6b590385f1300ddac605b475ed8536985/disconnect returned error: invalid name: "
Oct 27 13:36:46 myhost dockerd[1238]: time="2022-10-27T13:36:46.763284410-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=5276cac204527a25344183be31abef0592a91ce6c36c2160e16d4d5d59bde7c3 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
```

so it looks like an error when trying to disconnect from a docker network with no name?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue. See https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-cli/issues/589#issuecomment-872387555 for resolution. I'm loathe to update my kernel configuration just to get circleci cli to work, however, so FWIW I think I'll just stick to SSHing into builds for debugging: https://circleci.com/docs/ssh-access-jobs/.